# Hibernate 3.4.0: How to query for a scalar value

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, scalar

I have:   (MySQL 5.1)

```
CREATE TABLE `poh_faktury` (
  `cislo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
... 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

@Entity
@Table(name="poh_faktury")
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name="dalsiCisloFaktury", query="SELECT MAX(fakt.cislo) + 1 FROM Faktura AS fakt")
})
```

The generated queries (yes, two) are:

```
select MAX(faktura0_.cislo)+1 as col_0_0_ from poh_faktury faktura0_
select MAX(faktura0_.cislo)+1 as col_0_0_ from poh_faktury faktura0_ limit 2
```

But this

```
    Integer res = ((Integer) this.getJpaTemplate().execute( new JpaCallback() {
        public Object doInJpa( EntityManager em ) throws PersistenceException {
            Query q = em.createNamedQuery( "dalsiCisloFaktury" );
            return q.getSingleResult();
        }
    }));
```

puts `null` into `res`.

When I invoke SQL, it returns 1000 as it should:

```
SELECT MAX(fakt.cislo) + 1 FROM poh_faktury AS fakt;
```

How should I make Hibernate return correct scalar value?

Comment: Which SQL query does it generate? How is the cislo field defined an mapped?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. After restarting MySQL (to enable logs), the value is correct. I am about to delete the question. Thanks.

Comment: You could log the queries in hibernate rather than doing it in MySQL. It would be easier to diagnose problems this way.